# print second third of a linked list

Tags: list, linked-list, complexity-theory, pseudocode

**There is a list of n nodes.**

**I have to write a pseudo code that prints the nodes of the second third of the list by using 3 pointers. what is the complexity?**

if I could use by counter, it was easy, but it's forbidden.

I think about putting three pointers of the first three nodes, and then get next to the third pointer. if it's not the end node, get next to the second.. but my pseudo code is too long and complex.

**another question: how can I do it by using two pointers?**

for example: the list: 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9 sould prints the elements: 4,5,6.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the two-pointer solution, without counter, without double linked list

```
set the pointer1 in the 1st position
set the pointer2 in the 3rd position

while pointer2/=null{
pointer1.next
pointer2.next 3 times if pointer2=/null
}

//at this point we have the pointer1 in the first middle third element
//we only have to do the process again, but printing the elements
//we have to set the pointer2 to the third element, to start again

set the pointer2 in the 3rd position

while pointer2/=null{
pointer1.print
pointer1.next
pointer2.next 3 times if pointer2/=null
}
```

In the first iteration we put the pointer1 in the first element of the middle third, and in the second iteration we print all the elements we need, the trick is to reset the pointer2 when it arrives to the end for the first time

Answer (score 1):

- Set all of the pointers to the head of the list.
- While the pointer3 isn't null and its next isn't null, advance pointer1 by 1 node, pointer2 by 2 nodes, pointer3 by 3 nodes (stopping if you hit the end of course).
- Once pointer3 hits the end of the list, each pointer will be a 1/3 of the way through the list and you can just print all of the nodes between them.

Two pointers is just a variation on that, but it the way you wrote the question is a little vague

> the nodes of the second third of the list (2/3)

To me, the "second third" means the middle third of the list, but you wrote 2/3.

Comment: Thank you very much. I mean: for example, if there are 6 nodes: 1,2,3,4,5,6 so 2/3 mean to 3,4. if there are 9 nodes so 2/3 mean to 4,5,6..

Comment: Just making sure. So to do it with two pointers, just use pointers 2 and 3. For 9 nodes, that would place pointer 2 at node 6. Then do the same procedure but splitting the first part of the list in half (first moves 1, second moves 2).

Comment: I underdtood your first part: pointer 2 will get node number six and pointer 3 will get node number nine. while I do the same procedure of the first part of the list, I will use another three pointers, no? maybe I didnt understand this step.. if you can, please explain me again.

Comment: From scratch: - Set two pointers to the head of the list, - Advance pointer1 by 2, pointer2 by 3 until you get to the end of the list.  Then you recursively start over with the sublist before pointer 2, - Set two pointers to the head of the list, advance pointer1 by 1, pointer2 by 2 until you hit the end of the list. Now you have just halved the first 2/3 and you take the second half.

Answer (score 1):

With 2 Pointers is easy:
put the pointer1 in the 1st position
the pointer2 in the 3rd position

and do:

```
while pointer2 not null{
print pointer1
pointer1.next
print pointer1
pointer1.next
pointer2.next 3 times if pointer2 is not null
}
```

for example, the list is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

```
pointer1=1
pointer2=3

pointer2/=null then
print pointer1 (1)
pointer1.next
print pointer1 (2)
pointer1.next
pointer2=pointer2.next 3 times then pointer2=6
```

again

```
pointer2/null then
print pointer1 (3)
pointer1.next
print pointer1 (4)
pointer1.next
pointer2.next is null, then the program will terminate here
```

the list you got is 1,2,3,4 and it's the 2/3 of the 6 element list

any doubt answer here :)

Comment: thank you very much but I mean to the element of 3,4.. can you improve your answer please?

Comment: The only solution I can think to print the middle third elements with two pointers is using a counter :S

Comment: I found the solution without the counter and two pointers :) I'll write it now

Comment: wow! good! so if you can, please write the both solutions (with and without a counter)

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution with two pointers but the linked list must be a double-linked list (with next and prev)

```
set pointer 1 to the first element
set pointer 2 to the third element
while pointer 2/=null {
pointer1.next
pointer2.next 3 times if pointer2.next/=null
}
//in this part we have pointer1 in the first middle third element
while pointer1/=pointer2{
pointer1.next
pointer1.print
pointer2.prev
}
```

example with 1,2,3,4,5,6 again

```
pointer1=1
pointer2=3

pointer2.next/=null then
pointer1.next (pointer1=2)
pointer2.next 3 times, (pointer2=6)

pointer2.next=null then we enter in the second loop
pointer1.next  (pointer1=3)
pointer1.print (3)
pointer2.prev (pointer2=5)

pointer1/=pointer2 then
pointer1.next (pointer1=4)
pointer1.print(4)
pointer2.prev (pointer2=4)

pointer1==pointer2, end of program
```

we have 3,4 in the console output

Comment: nice solution! you are so clever.. thank you although my list is single list (only next)..